Using NET to create QGIS Plugin
I need to write a plugin for QGIS. I didn't find the package.Net, which would allow you to write a plugin (only Python and C++).
Can I use .Net to write a plugin for QGIS?

By default you can't, QGIS works only with Qt + C++ and Qt + Python plugins because .NET and C# libraries are not included in the standard QGIS installation. An official package for .NET doesn't exist and I don't know of any unofficial projects to provide it.
